# How can I print all the characters until a certain pattern (excluding the pattern itself) using grep/awk/sed?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

For example

```
echo "abc-1234a :" | grep <do-something>
```

to print only `abc-1234a`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  [What are you *really* trying to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/174723)?

Comment: What's the pattern? The colon? Blank-colon? Are you dealing with a single line of input only (as with your echo), or are you dealing with multiple lines of input?  If it's a multi-line input, are you looking for lines 1..N where N is the first line that contains the pattern, ignoring the rest, or are you looking for the initial segment of each line up to the pattern on that line?

Comment: Thanks guys! It's the characters in the first line of input before the colon. The input could have multiple line though.

Comment: Added an update to my answer to handle multi-line input.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think these are closer to what you're getting at, but without knowing what you're really trying to achieve, it's hard to say.

```
echo "abc-1234a :" | egrep -o '^[^:]+'
```

... though this will also match lines that have no colon.  If you only want lines with colons, and you *must* use only grep, this might work:

```
echo "abc-1234a :" | grep : | egrep -o '^[^:]+'
```

Of course, this only makes sense if your `echo "abc-1234a :"` is an example that would be replace with possibly multiple lines of input.

The smallest tool you could use is probably `cut`:

```
echo "abc-1234a :" | cut -d: -f1
```

And `sed` is always available...

```
echo "abc-1234a :" | sed 's/ *:.*//'
```

For this last one, if you only want to print lines that include a colon, change it to:

```
echo "abc-1234a :" | sed -ne 's/ *:.*//p'
```

Heck, you could even do this in pure bash:

```
while read line; do
  field="${line%%:*}"
  # do stuff with $field
done <<<"abc-1234a :"
```

For information on the `%%` bit, you can `man bash` and search for "*Parameter Expansion*".

**UPDATE**:

You said:

> **It's the characters in the first line of input before the colon. The
>   input could have multiple line though.**

The solutions with `grep` probably aren't your best choice, then, since they'll also print data from subsequent lines that might include colons.  Of course, there are many ways to solve this requirement as well.  We'll start with sample input:

```
$ function sample { printf "abc-1234a:foo\nbar baz:\nNarf\n"; }
$ sample
abc-1234a:foo
bar baz:
Narf
```

You could use multiple pipes, for example:

```
$ sample | head -1 | grep -Eo '^[^:]*'
abc-1234a
$ sample | head -1 | cut -d: -f1      
abc-1234a
```

Or you could use sed to process only the first line:

```
$ sample | sed -ne '1s/:.*//p'
abc-1234a
```

Or tell sed to exit after printing the first line (which is faster than reading the whole file):

```
$ sample | sed 's/:.*//;q'
abc-1234a
```

Or do the same thing but only show output if a colon was found (for safety):

```
$ sample | sed -ne 's/:.*//p;q'
abc-1234a
```

Or have awk do the same thing (as the last 3 examples, respectively):

```
$ sample | awk '{sub(/:.*/,"")} NR==1'
abc-1234a
$ sample | awk 'NR>1{nextfile} {sub(/:.*/,"")} 1'
abc-1234a
$ sample | awk 'NR>1{nextfile} sub(/:.*/,"")'
abc-1234a
```

Or in bash, with no pipes at all:

```
$ read line < <(sample)
$ printf '%s\n' "${line%%:*}"
abc-1234a
```

Comment: This is perfect! The second option works fine for me. I just wanted the characters before the colon in the first line of input. Thanks!

Comment: Would recommend a slight modification: `sed '/:/{ s/:.*//; q;}'` rather than assuming that only the first line of input is interesting.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - good point, though the OP did say (in a comment on the question) that the field name would only be found in the first line of input.

Comment: `egrep -o '^[^:]+'` == `grep -o '^[^:]\+'`

Comment: @kenorb - Not necessarily. While that's true for GNU grep, it's not true for all RE parsers. Compare your greps with the theoretically (but not) equivalent `sed -e 's/^\([^:]\+\).*/\1/'`. GNU sed behaves the same as GNU grep, but on FreeBSD, OSX, Solaris, etc, it does not. Interestingly, this behaviour is even backed up in Linux documentation -- from the [`regex(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html) man page, `'|', '+', and '?' are ordinary characters and there is no equivalent for their functionality.` Second last paragraph of the DESCRIPTION section.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do what you want with only sed.

Here is an example:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
filename=$1
pattern=yourpattern

# flag -n disables print everyline (default behavior)
sed -n "
  1,/$pattern/ {
    /$pattern/n # skip line containing pattern
    p           # print lines ranging from line 1 untill pattern
  }
" $filename

exit 0
```

This works at least for GNU's sed. It should work for other sed too, except
regarding the comments (some implementations of sed don't support comments).

Source: https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html