# Grep everything before a specific character

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have a file, `my_file`.
The contents of the file look like this:

```
4: something
5: something
7: another thing
```

I want to print out the following:

```
4
5
7
```

Basically I want to get all the numbers before the character `:`

Here is what I tried:

`grep -i "^[0-9]+(?=(:)" my_file`

This returned nothing. How can I change this command to make it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can grep show only words that match search pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546711/can-grep-show-only-words-that-match-search-pattern)

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of: [How can i print the all the characters until a certain pattern(excluding the pattern itself) using grep/awk/sed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360942/how-can-i-print-the-all-the-characters-until-a-certain-patternexcluding-the-pat) (`grep -o '^[^:]*'` works for your input), if you're looking for a PCRE-specific solution, state it explicitly in the question

Comment: @oguzismail grep -o '^[^:]*' won't work if there is a single letter that begins the line. It seems that the OP is asking for a PCRE.

Comment: @bhristov I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: For example, if we have a line that starts with a letter:
a123:
This will be matched by that regex.

Answer (score 3):

This is a use-case for `awk`:

```
$ awk -F":" '{print $1}' < inputfile
```

because you're using : as a field delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
grep -Eo "^[0-9]+" my_file # you can use either E (extended) or P (pearl) regular expressions
```

-o is for only matching

We also need to specify that we are using regex.

Both of the following will work:
-E extended regular expressions
-P pearl regular expressions

Breakdown:

```
^  signifies the start
  [0-9]  match a digit
       +  match 1 or more from [0-9]
```

Output:

```
4
5
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Using grep

```
grep -oE '^[0-9]+:' my_file |  tr -d ':'
```

using sed

```
sed 's#:.*$##g' my_file
```

Demo :

```
$cat test.txt 
4: something
5: something
7: another thing
$sed 's#:.*$##g' test.txt
4
5
7
$grep -oE '^[0-9]+:' test.txt |  tr -d ':'
4
5
7
```